# nodemon - error when run from package.json when server.js in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a node.js project (below is the root). And I cannot figure out how to run the server from package.json where I can run it from terminal.

```
node_modules
package.json
/server
/server/server.js
```

Previously it worked but now the package.json is in the root and the server.js is in the server directory

when I run the following command from root in terminal the server runs

```
cd ./server/ && nodemon server.js
```

When I run from root the command **npm run server**

I the following error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/server/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/server/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

My full json file is below

```
{
    "name": "Infoshot",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "description": "Research Tool",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "server": "cd ./server/ && nodemon server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix ../client/",
        "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd ../client && NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install  && CI= npm run build && echo this herokupostbuild been run"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "config": "^3.2.2",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.7.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
        "nodemailer-sendgrid": "^1.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
    }
}
```

(It used to work but I have moved the directories around so am trying to get it to work in this new configuration).

I have tried many combinations to get the script to work such as

```
        "server": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
        "server2": "nodemon server.js --prefix ./server/",
```

and many more but none seem to work. It worked when the package.json was in the same directory as the server.js but I don't want that.

Comment: Add script - "server": "nodemon server/sever.js"

Comment: unfortunatly that doesn't work - The error I get is  "Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/server/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182
    throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
    ^

Error: Configuration property "mongoURI" is not defined"

Comment: I think when I run it from the package.json it is looking for the node_modules in the server directory , but the install creates them in the root

Comment: No, it looks in the same directory, in which package,json is there.

Comment: try doing npm install again

Comment: can you show server/server.js file ?

Comment: sorry what  do you mean  show server/server.js file ? I delete all node modules and npm install and see if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224586/discussion-between-mohit-gupta-and-benny).

Comment: Ill try again in a few mins when the node_modules are reinstalled